# Why the belt not fitting on body with shrinkwrap?

Tags: modifiers

I have made the body and i want to fix the belt on the body. Im having 2 problem. 1st is the belt is on the body but its not having that rectangular shape. 2nd I have given the solidify to the belt but i cant see. How to fix the problem. Any suggestion or help Thanks
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 'project' option of the shrinkwrap modifier:

[image]

'Nearest surface point' may stretch the mesh to find the closer correspondence to the target.

'Project' projects along the object (belt here) surface's normal until it reaches the target.

Link to the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#mode

*Complement*

From there, if you add a solidify, you'll see that the two extremities of the belt overlap.

[image]

To avoid that, you'll need to use a vertex group to drive the shrinkwrap. But in this case, you have to apply the mirror modifier first, so that left and right parts can be different:

- Apply the mirror
- Enter edit mode
- Select all the vertices
- Create a group and assign the vertices to it
- Use this group in the shrinkwrap modifier (the modifier will now use these weights to moderate the influence of the shrinkwrap)

[image]

Now, switch to weight paint mode in order to change the vertex group's weights values:

- Enter in weight paint mode
- Enable vertex selection
- Choose/select the vertices on the right (or left)
- Choose a substract brush
- And tune until the wanted result is obtained

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying as show in the above image the front shape of the belt is curve and the back is in shape.

Comment: @ateks, I've seen that but I don't get what you mean in the comment? About the solidify, just add it after the shrinkwrap. But if you want right or left front part of the belt to be above the other one, you'll need to apply the mirror and use a vertex group (correctly weighted) for the shrinwrap.